# Apps larger than 50MB prohibited by the App Store

Tags: ios-appstore, developer-program

If we read the App Store Review Guidelines for iOS there is a point that

> - **2.15** Apps larger than 50MB in size will not download over cellular networks (this is automatically prohibited by the App Store)

Why this is so we all know that there are thousands of apps which have size far greater then 50MB?

Comment: We can all speculate as to why, but is there a problem you are trying to overcome or some practical issue you're trying to get over given that a line has been drawn on download sizes, and at present that line is 50 MB of data?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see the limit relates to the cellular network downloads. The AppleStore app itself takes care of this limitation.

Over wifi you have no limit on apps download.

Comment: There are so many points there in the guidelines which are not allowed but apps are using that. For example last week i publish two apps having same functionality but just graphics changed .one was accepted and second one was rejected. and they say that you layout is not according to as apple recommend

Comment: This comment is just irrelevant to the topic here. You can contact apple if you think the rejection was invalid.